# How to draw the following in latex

Tags: tikz-styles

[image]

I want to draw the following graphs in latex. Can u please help me to draw them

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Sorry but, at the moment, your question is _just-do-it-for-me_ and also unclear.

Answer (score 4):

You have a lot of similar figures so I will only go through the idea that I would use. First of all the tikz library `positioning` can help you to get the things at the right places. Then define a node type that is circular with appropriate radius (here 3mm) and filled black. Below this is called `plupp`.

That is, to get two nodes you can do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  plupp/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=3pt,fill=black},
  node distance=2cm and 4cm,%% y and x distance for positioning
  ]
  \node[plupp,label=-90:NB1](NB1){};
  \node[plupp,label=-90:NB2,right=of NB1](NB2){};
  \draw (NB1) -- (NB2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Then add two more nodes above these two and draw lines between them.

```
\node[plupp,label=90:RC1,above=of NB1](RC1){};
\node[plupp,label=90:RC2,above=of NB2](RC2){};
\draw (NB1) -- (RC1) -- (RC2) -- (NB2);
```

[image]

In some figures you also have nodes without lines. Here is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  plupp/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=3pt,fill=black},
  node distance=2cm and 4cm,%% y and x distance for positioning
  ]
  \node[plupp,label=-90:NB1](NB1){};
  \node[plupp,label=-90:NB2,right=of NB1](NB2){};
  \draw (NB1) -- (NB2);
  \node[plupp,label=90:RC1,above=of NB1](RC1){};
  \node[plupp,label=90:RC2,above=of NB2](RC2){};
  \draw (NB1) -- (RC1) -- (RC2) -- (NB2);
  \node[plupp,label=90:NRC1,above=of RC1](NRC1){};
  \node[plupp,label=90:NRC2,above=of RC2](NRC2){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, great answer, more than the question (as is) deserves!